# MVC route ordering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these two rules

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Custom", "X{controller}/{action}");
```

There is a contoller named "Custom" and method "Index" but calling **localhost/XCustom/Index** gives me a 404.

I have read that routes are tried until a match is found.
Since the url doesn't match the first route why doesn't try to match the second.

*I know that this works if I change the route ordering.

Comment: It does match the first one (it tries to find a controller named `XCustom` (which does not exist). And you have not specified the controller and action for the second one

Comment: I thought match means also finding the controller

Comment: Fortunately it doesn't, otherwise you would need to write a route for every controller and action in your project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that with `{controller}/{action}` route, the system tries to find the controller named `XCustomController` which you don't have. So in fact the url matched your route, you failed to supply a valid controller for it.